# Differential equation approach needed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation

$X(t)=k(\cos at-\cos bt)$ for some positive parameters $k,a,b$

Now I would like to find a t such that $x=x'=0$ (Or really near to zero). I tried all the basic approach without winning something.

After some arrangements I found the following equation from the derivative of x:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin bt}{\sin at}$$ Furthermore from x I know that x is zero at points $t=\frac{2\pi n}{a+b}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So plugging into the first equation I should solve the equation for some of this n.

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin\left(b\frac{2\pi n}{a+b}\right)}{\sin\left(a\frac{2\pi n}{a+b}\right)}$$

I was also thinking about the dirichlet kernel which has a very similar form but it did not help much. Any help is appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't $x=0$ give you $t=\frac{2\pi n}{a-b},\ n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Also, $t=0$ is an immediate solution.

Comment: Yes t=0 is one solution but here I want one which is not zero :)

Comment: I have plus since $cos(at)=cos(bt) \Rightarrow at=-bt$

Comment: Ok, u can take that.

Comment: One funny thing, you get from the last equation $a=-b\ \forall n\ne 0$, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter $k$ plays no rôle.

After rewriting the difference of cosines as product of sines and scaling the variable $t$ we may as well assume
$$x(t)=\sin(t)\sin(\lambda t)\tag{1}$$
with $\lambda>1$.  It follows that $x(t)=0$ iff 
$$t=k\pi\quad\vee\quad t={l\pi\over \lambda}, \qquad k,\>l\in{\mathbb Z}\ .$$
Now
$$x'(t)=\cos(t)\sin(\lambda t)+\lambda \sin(t)\cos(\lambda t)\ .$$
When $x'(t)=0$ and $t=k\pi\ne0$ then necessarily $\sin(\lambda t)=0$, which implies $t={l\pi\over \lambda}$. This in turn implies $\lambda={l\over k}\in{\mathbb Q}$. Similarly: When $x'(t)=0$ and $t={l\pi\over \lambda}\ne0$ then necessarily $\sin t=0$, or $t=k\pi$. This again implies $\lambda={l\over k}\in{\mathbb Q}$.

It follows that the functions $x(\cdot)$ and $x'(\cdot)$ only have  common zeros other than $t=0$ when ${a\over b}$ is rational. In this case the two functions are periodic.

We therefore replace $(1)$ by
$$x(t)=\sin(p t)\sin(qt), \quad p, q\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1},\quad {\rm gcd}(p,q)=1\ .$$
It is then easily seen that the period of $x(\cdot)$ is $2\pi$ or $\pi$, and that the common zeros of $x(\cdot)$ and $x'(\cdot)$ are the "trivial" ones, namely  $t=m\pi$, $\>m\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $X(t)$ as a Fourier series and then try to solve it.